# Sorting an array of dictionaries in Plist

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

Trying to sort an array of dictionaries. There are two arrays in the plist file and I am trying to sort one of them and having a lot of trouble. I can extract the dictionaries into a NSArray and sort the files.

I can only do this by extracting the dictionaries so when I try to save the information back to the plist I've lost my structure and other array of dictionaries.
How can I sort the array correctly. I understand I'm extracting the array and then saving it as it's own file. I see what I'm doing wrong but can't figure how the correct way.

```
NSArray *array =  [dict valueForKey:@"Lighting"];
NSSortDescriptor* nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Controller Zone" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];

NSString *pathToFileExportSorted = @"/Users/scott/Desktop/plistPreSEsorted.plist";
[sortedArray writeToFile:pathToFileExportSorted atomically: YES];
```

I have tried something like this but couldn't get that working either

```
    [array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Lighting.Controller Zone" ascending:YES]]];
```

I just want to sort the Array Lighting by "Controller Zone" and keep the plist as is otherwise.

Thanks for any help.

Original Data:

[image]

What I am currently Exporting, does not have Lighting and Shade array. The array is now the only thing in the plist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's needed to assign sorted array to `Lighting` key
- ...and to save your initial dictionary with changed `Lighting` key

  ```
  NSArray *array = [dict valueForKey:@"Lighting"];
  NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Controller Zone" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];

  NSMutableDictionary *dictToSave = [[dict mutableCopy] autorelease];
  [dictToSave setObject:sortedArray forKey:@"Lighting"];

  NSString *pathToFileExportSorted = @"/Users/scott/Desktop/plistPreSEsorted.plist";
  [dictToSave writeToFile:pathToFileExportSorted atomically:YES];
  ```

That should work as you've described.

Comment: I was looking for something like set object. Thank you I will try this tonight.